# Oracle in-line method to produce CSV for relation

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following tables:

```
ALERT (ID,Name)
   1  |  Alert A
   2  |  Alert B


ALERT_BRAND_XREF (ALERT_ID, BRAND_ID)
   1  | 1
   1  | 2
   2  | 1

BRAND (ID, NAME)
  1  | Brand A
  2  | Brand B
```

I am trying to write one statement to return a list of alerts with the applicable brands as a CSV list in one field.  Desired results:

```
 Alert A  |  Brand A, Brand B
 Alert B  |  Brand A
```

Is there a way to do this without writing a separate function?  I would like to do it in one self-contained SQL statement if possible.

This is Oracle 9i.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL this would be easy with the `GROUP_CONCAT()` function, but it looks like to do the equivalent in Oracle it's a little messy:

[Oracle group_concat() updated (again)](http://halisway.blogspot.com/2006/08/oracle-groupconcat-updated-again.html)

Answer (score 1):

Look to [this solutions](http://blog.lishman.com/2008/05/how-to-pivot-column-to-csv-list-in.html), its very useful. Using SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH and analytic functions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to turn a repeating group into a comma setarated list.
It uses the MODEL clause of Oracle's dialect of SQL.  (Oracle 10g)

http://plsqlnotes.blogspot.com/2007/09/using-model-for-generating-csv-by_2227.html#links

(Replaces my previous wrong answer).

Comment: I wasn't aware of a built-in CSV generator.  Any other details?  Link?

Comment: Oops, my blunder.  I didn't read your problem carefully.  I thought you were trying to dump the whole thing to a CSV file.  Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

In oracle you can use wm_concat()

```
SELECT a.Name , wm_concat(b.Name) FROM 
   ALERT a, 
   ALERT_BRAND_XREF  abx ,
   BRAND b 
  where a.id = abx.ALERT_ID 
   and abx.BRAND_ID = b.id 
  group by  a.Name;
```